# How to find a subset of potentially maximal vectors (of numbers) in a set of vectors

Tags: algorithms, computational-geometry, discrete-mathematics

I have a set S (so no duplicates) of d-dimensional vectors of non-negative real numbers (or if you would prefer, floats).

I say a vector u "covers" a vector v if, in every dimension 1..d, u[i] >= v[i]. So for d=3, (3,3,2) covers (2, 3, 1), but (3, 3, 1) doesn't cover (2, 2, 2).

I am interested in finding a subset T of S, such that for every v in T, there is no u in S with u != v, such that u covers v.  Alternatively, I'm interested in removing from S those vectors that are covered by other vectors in S.

What is an efficient algorithm for this?  Barring that, what is at least the "real name" of this problem to help me search for it?

An O(n^2) algorithm is obvious: for every vector in S, check it against every other vector in S, and add it to T if nothing covers it.  I'm having trouble doing much better than that.

I have considered trying to use kd-trees and range trees, but this is for a real world problem, and in practice d is too high and the number of vectors too low, so that e.g. the O(n * log^d(n)) running time is actually worse than the naive O(n^2).  (d is approximately 20-40, and the number of vectors is in the millions).

**Edit - Particular Problem Details**

As requested, more information about the specific problem I am trying to solve.

The implementation problem at hand involves several sets of vectors, approximately 60-100 sets, each with about 10-20 vectors in them. For every set s, for every vector v in s, v has dimension d, and all axes of v are zero save for one which is positive. A result vector is formed by choosing precisely one vector from each set and adding them together, and a given result vector is strictly worse if it is covered (or apparently the real word is 'dominated') by another result vector. You can assume the non-zero axis of a base vector varies uniformly in [.9, 1.1].  In practice most intermediate results appear to be dominated, and size(T) << size(S)

Comment: One keyword that might be of interest to you is "partial ordering". When you say $u$ *covers* $v$, essentially you mean $u \ge v$, where the inequality holds entrywise. Then problem is that you cannot *order* vectors the same way you would order a sequence of real numbers. But there exists a concept of *partial ordering*. From such an ordering you want to get the largest possible *antichain*.

Comment: Isn't maximal anti-chain different? Consider {(0, 2), (1, 1), (2, 0), (3,3)} - the largest antichain is (0,2), (1, 1), (2, 0); but the result T is just (3,3) and seems unrelated.  At any rate, further clarification of largest anti-chain -> T would be appreciated and probably constitute an answer.

Comment: Apologies. I misread the question and rushed to give keywords. But now for your question: It seems that you want to create a Directed acyclic graph on $n$ vertices corresponding to vectors. $u$ has an edge towards $v$ if $v$ covers $u$. Then you want to find all "sink" nodes. Anything that is not a sink, is covered by some other guy. Right? I guess that is the naive $O(n^2)$... I will try to think about it. But the bottleneck is to create the DAG (i.e. find the partial order). Maybe you can look for efficient ways to do that?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You're looking for a set of Pareto-optimal alternatives.  If you're looking for all such possibilities (i.e., looking to make $T$ as large as possible), you're looking for the Pareto-optimal front.  You asked for keywords or names to search for this -- those are standard terms for this concept.  See https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Multi-objective_optimization.

For specific situations, if the data is structured, it may be possible to take into account knowledge of the structure of the data to find a better algorithm -- but this will depend on the nature of the data.

---

In your specific case, there are algorithmic techniques that might lead to significant improvements in running time.  In particular, in your setting, each vector $v \in S$ is obtained as a sum of some component vectors $v = \sum_i v_i$, where we have a collection of sets $S_1,S_2,\dots,S_k$ and each $v_i$ is chosen from some set $S_i$.

Let me establish some notation and definitions, prove some mathematical results, and then show them how to compute the Pareto-optimal front for your specific situation.

**Definition.** We say that $u$ dominates $v$ if $u[j] \ge v[j]$ for all dimensions $j$.  (This is the same as what you call "covers", but "dominates" is the more standard term.)

**Definition 1.** If $S,T$ are sets, then $S+T$ is defined to be the set $S+T=\{s+t : s \in S, t \in T\}$.

**Definition 2.** If $S$ is a set of vectors, define $P(S)$ to be the Pareto-optimal front of $S$, i.e., the set of vectors $s \in S$ such that there does not exist any vector $t \in T$ that dominates $s$.

Your problem is the following: given sets $S_1,\dots,S_k$ of vectors, find the Pareto-optimal front of $S_1+\dots + S_k$, i.e., compute $P(S_1 + \dots + S_k)$.  I'll show an algorithm to compute this.

The following lemmas will be helpful:

**Lemma 1.** If $u$ dominates $v$, then $u+w$ dominates $v+w$.

**Lemma 2.** If $u_i$ dominates $v_i$ for each $i$, then $\sum_i u_i$ dominates $\sum_i v_i$.

**Lemma 3.** $P(S+T) = P(P(S)+P(T))$.

(Lemmas 2 and 3 follow immediately from Lemma 1.)

We'll now use Lemma 3 repeatedly to compute $P(S_1 + \dots + S_k)$.  We build a binary tree over the $k$ leaves $S_1,\dots,S_k$.  At each node, we compute the Pareto-optimal front of the sum of the two sets corresponding to its two children.

In other words, here's how we compute the Pareto-optimal front for several values of $k$:

$$P(S_1+S_2) = P(P(S_1)+P(S_2)).$$

$$P(S_1+S_2+S_3+S_4) = P(P(P(S_1)+P(S_2)) + P(P(S_3)+P(S_4))).$$

(In other words, to compute $P(S_1+S_2+S_3+S_4)$, we first compute $U_1 = P(S_1+S_2)$ efficiently using Lemma 3 and $U_2 = P(S_3 + S_4)$ using Lemma 3, then we compute $P(U_1+U_2)$ and use Lemma 3 to conclude that this is equal to $P(S_1+S_2+S_3+S_4)$.)

You can see how this works recursively.  To compute $P(S_1+\dots + S_k)$, we divide the sets in half, recursively compute $X=P(S_1+\dots + S_{k/2})$ and $Y=P(S_{k/2+1} + \dots + S_k)$ using the efficient algorithm, and then compute $P(X+Y)$.

At each stage of the binary tree, we are filtering out all dominated vectors.  If you're lucky, this greatly reduces the number of possibilities that remain at each level of the binary tree.

I suggest you try this on your specific application.  If, as you say, the final size of $P(S_1+\dots + S_k)$ is not too large (say $m$), then this should be efficient: the size at each internal node of the tree will be no larger than $m$, so the time to merge the two children of any node will be $O(m^3)$ [using the trivial quadratic algorithm mentioned in the question], and the total running time will be at most $O(m^3 k)$.  In practice, the actual running time might be significantly faster than that.

---

You could also explore different algorithms for computing $P(\cdot)$, the Pareto-optimal front of a set.  There are basically two standard algorithms: the "simple cull" algorithm [which is the same as the quadratic-time algorithm you mentioned in the question], and a recursive divide-and-conquer algorithm.

The simple cull algorithm has $O(n^2)$ worst-case running time, as you say.  Actually, if we know that the Pareto-optimal front has size $m$, the running time is a bit better: the running time is $O(mn)$.  (In other words, if we let $n=|S|$ and $m=|P(S)|$, then you can compute $P(S)$ from $S$ in $O(nm)$ time.)  The divide-and-conquer algorithm has $O(n (\log n)^{d-1})$ worst-case running time, which as you say in the question will likely be too small for your parameters.

However, it is also possible to combine the two techniques, where you use the recursive divide-and-conquer algorithm but once the problem size becomes small enough you switch to the simple cull algorithm.  Whether this will lead to any improvement in your actual setting can probably only be determined through experimentation.

For an overview of these algorithms, see for example Section of the following paper:

[A Calculator for Pareto Points](http://alexandria.tue.nl/openaccess/Metis215075.pdf). Marc Geilen and Twan Basten.  Design, Automation & Test in Europe Conference & Exhibition 2007 (DATE'07), IEEE.

To compute $P(P(S)+P(T))$, the best algorithm I know is to compute $S'=P(S)$ and $T'=P(T)$ using one of the above methods, then compute $S'+T'$ using the obvious quadratic-time algorithm (combine all pairs), then compute $P(S'+T')$ using one of the above methods.

Comment: This answer is excellent, but unfortunately (as of March 13 2015) does not treat a critical step: calculating P(X+Y).  After some googling about "Pareto Frontier" I would recommend the multidimensional divide and conquer method of Bentley and Kung for that purpose, touched on here: http://citeseerx.ist.psu.edu/viewdoc/summary?doi=10.1.1.78.9827

Comment: @JamesDowdell, thank you for the suggestion.  I've edited the answer to add extensive discussion and resources on those matters to the end of my answer.  Does this look better?