# An online algorithm to find the Pareto frontier elements

Tags: algorithms, search-algorithms

I'm looking for an online algorithm that takes a stream of elements and preserves the elements that are on the [Pareto frontier](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Pareto_efficiency#Pareto_frontier) (e.g. all non-dominated elements).

For instance. Given the following inputs, the retained Pareto frontier set would evolved as follows:

- `(3,7)`

  - insert element b/c it's the first element
  - pareto set now includes `{(3,7)}`
- `(7,3)`

  - insert element b/c it's not dominated in the first
  - pareto set now includes `{(3,7), (7,3)}`
- `(8,4)`

  - insert element b/c it's not dominated; remove `(7,3)` which it is dominated in both dimensions
  - pareto set now includes `{(3,7), (8,4)}`
- `(1,1)`

  - do not insert because it's dominate in both dimensions
  - pareto set now includes `{(3,7), (8,4)}`
- `(9,9)`

  - insert element b/c it's not dominated; remove all other elements because this dominates them in both dimensions
  - pareto set now includes `{(9,9)}`

In my example I'm using 2-tuples, but I'm looking for an algorithm that could handle N-tuples for "small" N (say <10).

The naive solution is to just to compare each element with all elements currently in the set. In practice the naive approach might not be so bad (e.g. sub $O(n^2)$) because elements will regularly be expelled by the comparison set. But I was wondering if there was a known efficient algorithm for this. I'm interested in efficiency in memory and in computational complexity. (Ha! And as a matter of fact, I'm looking for the set of algorithms that are Pareto optimal with respect to memory and computational complexity.)

My current application of this is in building a [Lucene](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Lucene) search-document `Collector` that doesn't collect the most relevant documents (the typical use case for a search engine), but collects the Pareto optimal documents along specified dimensions.

Comment: Are you interested in the [amortized cost](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Amortized_analysis) or the maximum of each update's cost? ​ ​

Comment: Pareto frontier is also called skyline or maxima. So try keywords like "online, skyline/maxima, data stream, maintain" with google.

Comment: This paper has several solutions
https://dl.acm.org/citation.cfm?doid=1142473.1142530

Answer (score 4, accepted):

In two dimensions, each update can be done in $O(\lg n)$ time, by using a balanced binary tree data structure.  But when you are working in a high-dimensional space, I don't know of any efficient solution.

Let me describe an efficient algorithm for the 2D case.  Let $F$ denote the set of points in the Pareto frontier.  Store $F$ in a balanced binary tree, using the $x$-coordinate of each point as its key.  Note that when you sort $F$ by increasing $x$-coordinate, they'll also be sorted by decreasing $y$-coordinate.

Now, given a new point $(x_q,y_q)$, you can check efficiently whether it is Pareto-dominated by any element of $F$.  Find the first element of $F$ to the right of $(x_q,y_q)$ (i.e., the element $(x,y) \in F$ such that $x \ge x_q$ and $x$ is minimal); then checking whether it dominates $(x_q,y_q)$.

Also, given a new point $(x_q,y_q)$, you can efficiently find whether it Pareto-dominates any element of $F$.  In particular, you can find indices $i,j$ such that the points $(x_i,y_i),(x_{i+1},y_{i+1}),\dots,(x_j,y_j)$ of $F$ are all Pareto-dominated by $(x_q,y_q)$ (assuming that the points of $F$ have been ordered by $x$-coordinate, Pareto-dominated points will be in a consecutive interval).  Here's how.  Find the first element of $F$ to the left of $(x_q,y_q)$ (i.e., the element $(x_j,y_j) \in F$ such that $x_j \le x_q$ and $x_j$ is as large as possible), and check whether $(x_q,y_q)$ dominates it.  If yes, find the smallest index $i$ such that $i<j$ (so $x_i<x_j$) and $y_i \le y_q$.  Both of these steps can be done in $O(\lg n)$ time.  (Finding $i$ can be done in $O(\lg n)$ time by treating the tree as branching on the $y$-coordinate of points, and taking advantage of the fact that the points of $F$ are sorted by decreasing $y$-coordinate.)

Now this tell us what to do.  If $(x_q,y_q)$ is dominated by some point of $F$, then don't add it to $F$; you're done.  Alternatively, if $(x_q,y_q)$ dominate points $i..j$ of $F$, then you need to delete those points from $F$ and add $(x_q,y_q)$ into $F$.  This can be done in $O(\lg n)$ time, by noting that any interval of consecutive indices can be expressed as the union of $O(\lg n)$ subtrees of the binary tree (roughly speaking, you work with the siblings of the nodes along the path from $i$ to the root, and the same for the path from $j$ to the root); you can delete each subtree in $O(1)$ time.  This lets us delete an entire range of consecutive points in $F$ in $O(\lg n)$ time, no matter how large the range is.  For details, see [Delete a consecutive range of leaves from a binary tree](https://cs.stackexchange.com/q/52457/755).

All of this can be done in $O(\lg n)$ time, using a balanced binary tree data structure.

This works in 2 dimensions (i.e., 2-tuples).  In higher dimensions, the problem gets much harder.  You can find references to the literature, with techniques for higher dimensions, at [How to find a subset of potentially maximal vectors (of numbers) in a set of vectors](https://cs.stackexchange.com/q/40142/755); but I'm afraid that in high dimensions, all the known algorithms are likely to be fairly slow (they have a factor that is something like $O((\lg n)^{d-1})$ where $d$ is the number of dimensions).

Comment: Do balanced binary trees allow ​ O($\hspace{.02 in}$log(n))-time ​ deletions of _ranges_? ​ ​ ​ ​

Comment: This is a good answer. Though it brings to my attention that I implied a constraint with my example that I didn't intend to. In my example I'm using 2-tuples, but I would need an algorithm that handles N-tuples.

Comment: @JnBrymn, see my updated answer: I added a paragraph to the end to address the situation in higher dimensions.

Comment: See "remove all other elements because this dominates them in both dimensions". ​ (There can easily be a linear number elements to be removed, so if you have to do that one element at a time, then updates can take worst-case O(n) time.) ​ ​ ​ ​

Comment: In two dimensions, how are now-strictly-dominated elements removed in O(log(n)) time? ​ ​

Comment: @RickyDemer, I've updated my answer to address that point.  You're right: we might potentially need to delete an entire range of consecutive points in the frontier.  Fortunately, that too can be done in $O(\lg n)$ time, using properties of balanced binary trees.  Do you agree?  If you agree, shall we clean up our comments?

Comment: I don't see how such subtrees can all be found in O(log(n)) time. ​ ​

Comment: @RickyDemer, that aspect is probably of independent interest, so let's take that to a separate question: http://cs.stackexchange.com/q/52457/755.