# Delete a consecutive range of leaves from a binary tree

Tags: data-structures, binary-trees, intervals

Suppose I have a binary tree containing $n$ leaves and whose depth is $d$, where the data is in the leaves (the internal nodes don't hold data values).

I want to delete a consecutive interval of leaves.  In other words, suppose we order the leaves from left to right and number them $1,2,\dots,n$.  I am given a pair of indices $i,j$, and I want to delete leaves $i,i+1,\dots,j-1,j$.  This operation should also delete an interior node if all of its descendant-leaves are deleted.

Can this be done efficiently?  Can it be done in $O(d)$ time, regardless of $i,j$?

Comment: Can we augment the tree? Should the tree be balanced after the operation?

Answer (score 1):

Yes.  This can be done in $O(d)$ time.  As a nice consequence, if we have a balanced binary tree, then $d = O(\lg n)$, so range-deletion can be done in $O(\lg n)$ time, regardless of how large the range is.

This is hard to explain without a picture, but the key insight is this: it suffices to delete a set $S$ of nodes, where $S$ can be chosen so that $|S| \le 2d$.  (This will of course delete all of the descendants of every node in $S$.)  Since $|S| = O(d)$, the running time to delete the nodes in $S$ will be $O(d)$.  In other words, the interval $[i,j]$ can be expressed as a union of $O(d)$ subtrees.  Roughly speaking, the set $S$ will be chosen by taking a subset of the siblings of the nodes on the path from $i$ or $j$ to the root.

In particular, we will define

$$S = \{n : L(n) \subseteq [i,j] \text{ and } L(\text{parent}(n)) \not\subseteq [i,j]\},$$

where $L(n)$ is the set of leaves that are descendants of $n$.  I will show first that deleting $S$ has the desired effect, and second that that $|S| \le 2d$, from which it will follow that the range-deletion can be done in $O(\lg d)$ time.

**Lemma 1.** Deleting $S$ will have the effect of deleting leaves $i,i+1,\dots,j-1,j$ but not any of the other leaves.

*Proof.* Consider any leaf $\ell$ with $i \le \ell \le j$.  Then $\ell$ is a descendant of some $n \in S$: if $\ell \notin S$, then some ancestor of $S$ must be in $S$ (imaging walking up from $\ell$ along the path towards the root; consider the last ancestor $n$ of $S$ such that $L(n) \subseteq [i,j]$; since $L(\ell) =\{\ell\} \subseteq [i,j]$, such an ancestor must exist).  Conversely, a leaf $\ell$ is deleted only if it is a descendant of some $n \in S$; but by construction, $L(n) \subseteq [i,j]$ and $\ell \in L(n)$, so it follows that if leaf $\ell$ is deleted, $\ell \in [i,j]$.

Now let's show that $|S| \le 2d$.  Let $P(\ell)$ denote the set of nodes along the path from $\ell$ to the root.  Let $Q(\ell)$ denote the set of siblings of the nodes in $P(\ell)$ ($\ell$'s sibling, $\ell$'s parent's sibling, $\ell$'s parent's parent's sibling, and so on).  Then I claim:

**Lemma 2.** $|Q(\ell)| \le d$ for all $\ell$.

*Proof.* Since the tree has height $d$, $|P(\ell)| \le d$.  Now $|Q(\ell)| \le |P(\ell)| \le d$.

**Lemma 3.** $S \subseteq Q(i) \cup Q(j)$.

*Proof.* Suppose $n \in S$, so that $L(n) \subseteq [i,j]$ but $L(\text{parent}(n)) \not\subseteq [i,j]$.  Let $m$ be $n$'s sibling.  Note that $L(\text{parent}(n)) = L(n) \cup L(m)$.  It follows that we must have $L(m) \not\subseteq [i,j]$ (otherwise $L(\text{parent}(n)) \subseteq [i,j]$ and $n$ wouldn't be in $S$).  Also $L(n) \cap L(m) = \emptyset$ and $L(n)$ and $L(m)$ are adjacent intervals ($L(n) \cup L(m)$ is itself an interval; there is no gap in between $L(n)$ and $L(m)$).  It follows that either $i \in L(m)$ or $j \in L(m)$, i.e., $m$ must be an ancestor of either $i$ or $j$, i.e., either $m \in Q(i)$ or $m \in Q(j)$.

**Lemma 4.** $|S| \le 2d$.

*Proof.* Follows from Lemma 2, Lemma 3, and the union bound.

---

Caveat: I haven't checked whether rebalancing can also be done in $O(d)$ time.  For instance, for a balanced binary tree like an AVL tree or a red-black tree, we have $d=O(\lg n)$, and it would be nice if we could delete the entire range in $O(\lg n)$ time.  However, it's not clear whether this is possible.  While we can indeed delete the nodes in $S$ in $O(\lg n)$ time, I haven't checked whether it's possible to do all necessary subsequent rebalancing operations in $O(\lg n)$ time.  Rebalancing is certainly doable in $O((\lg n)^2)$ time, but I don't know whether it can be done in $O(\lg n)$ time.

Comment: "This is hard to explain without a picture" -- there's an easy fix for that. ;)

Comment: Am I missing something or have you skipped rebalancing? It is quite clear that we can find all affected leaves and can remove them in time $O(d)$, but no balanced tree variant I know has $O(1)$ worst-case deletion, so extra care has to be taken.

Comment: @Raphael, good point -- I have skipped rebalancing.  I *think* that doesn't increase the asymptotic cost, because rebalancing only "touches" the ancestors of the nodes that you deleted, and in this construction, while there are $2d$ nodes to delete, they have in total only $\le 2d$ ancestors (not $\Theta(d^2)$ as one would expect for the general case).  But I haven't gone through all the steps for deletion in a balanced tree carefully to be sure this all works out...

Comment: If both AVL and Red-Black trees (iirc) rebalancing after a deletion may propagate up to the root, in which case you get cost in the order of the height of the tree, for a total cost of $\Omega(d + \log n)$.

Comment: @Raphael, I'm not following where you got $\Omega(d+\lg n)$ from.  Yes, rebalancing may propagate up to the root, which means that rebalancing only "touches" each node on the path from $x$ (the node you're deleting) to the root.  There are only $\le d$ such nodes, since the tree has depth $d$.  That's why I think the running time might still be $O(d)$.  (For a balanced binary tree, $d = \Theta(\lg n)$.)

Comment: Oh, $d$ is your depth. My bad, I thought is was the number of to-be-deleted nodes. So, $d \in \Theta(\log n)$? Then this *may* work, provided you can combine the deletion operations in a meaningful way that avoids having to do the rebalancing for every removed node individually. I for one don't know how to do that for AVL and red-black.