# An online algorithm to maintain the Pareto frontier elements

Tags: algorithms, data-structures, pareto

I'm looking for an online algorithm/datastructure that is able to maintain a pareto frontier for two dimensional elements in an online scenario where elements can be added and deleted.

For example:

- `insert((3,7))`

  - since the pareto front is empty it has to be added to it
  - set of elements `E={(3,7)}`
  - pareto frontier `P={(3,7)}`
- `insert((7,3))` and `insert((10,2))`

  - both have to be added to pareto frontier (since they arent dominated)
  - set of elements `E={(3,7), (7,3), (10,2)}`
  - pareto frontier `P={(3,7), (7,3), (10,2)}`
- `insert((8,4))`

  - is dominated by `(7,3)` so do not add it to the pareto frontier (but keep it in the set of elements `E` because its maybe going to be part of the pareto frontier later)
  - set of elements `E={(3,7), (7,3), (10,2), (8,4)}`
  - pareto frontier `P={(3,7), (7,3), (10,2)}`
- `remove((7,3))`

  - remove `(7,3)` from the set of elements and from the pareto frontier. The pareto frontier has to adjust accordingly and therefore `(8,4)` is added to the pareto frontier now.
  - set of elements `E={(3,7), (10,2), (8,4)}`
  - pareto frontier `P={(3,7), (10,2), (8,4)}`

This question is similiar to [An online algorithm to find the Pareto frontier elements](https://cs.stackexchange.com/questions/52201/an-online-algorithm-to-find-the-pareto-frontier-elements), but in the scenario described above points can also be removed. A brute force algorithm would have quadratic time complexity and I am looking for something better.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can find an answer to this in ["Dynamic Planar Range Maxima Queries", by Brodal and Tsakalidis](https://users-cs.au.dk/gerth/papers/icalp11.pdf). They support `insert` and `remove` in $O(\log n)$ time. That paper points to several previous papers that addressed the question as well.

In particular, I expect the simplest solution can be found in sections 8 and 9 of ["Maintenance of Configurations in the Plane", Technical Report RUU-CS-79-9, by Overmars and van Leeuwen](http://www.cs.uu.nl/research/techreps/repo/CS-1979/1979-09.pdf), ([mirror](https://dspace.library.uu.nl/bitstream/handle/1874/15899/overmars_79_maintenance_of.pdf)). Their solution takes $O(\log^2 n)$ for each `insert` or `remove`.